# $.JQuery.Query removing zeros from my numeric querystring value

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery Querystring plugin for getting the Querystrings.

I have below code:

```
if ($.query.get("mode"))
        {
            //alert("mode");
            var newUrl;
            var t1 = ($.query);            
            newUrl = $.query.REMOVE("mode");    
            $.query.toString();               
            currentPageLink = reloadURL.split("?")[0] + $.query.set("mode", "ssl");                       
        }
```

The problem is that when I am using `$.query.set("mode", "ssl")` its removing my numeric 00 from 001 values, I mean if any of mine querystring is numeric for example "....?accountno=001" after doing $.query.set it is changing it into ?accountno=1,

Please suggest!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>$.query seems to typecast your accountno as an integer instead of a string (which would preserve the two leading zeroes).</strike>

There appears to be a bug in the regex used to determine whether a parameter is a int or not. Currently, even strings leading zeroes (and only number characters) are typecasted. They shouldn't be.

In line 89 of the [latest query plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.query-2.1.7.js.txt), the regex, `/^[+-]?[0-9]+$/`, can be rewritten and that should do it. I was going to suggest `/^[+-]?[1-9][0-9]*$/`, but this regex misses the case of "0".

Comment: Yeah, I know that, can you please suggest how to do that? Thanks